# Trying to convert image to Base64 string in javascript and trying to convert to byte array in c#, gives Invalid character in base64 string error

Tags: javascript, c#, base64, converters

I am trying to convert an file input image in javascript as follows;

```
function getBase64(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log(reader.result);
    return reader.result;
}
```

sending string with json to Web Service and trying to convert to byte array as follows;

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
```

getting Invalid character in base64 string error.

Converted string array:[pastebin converted string array](https://pastebin.com/E4kczVNF)

[Image I am trying to convert](https://imagebin.ca/v/4W83nZUeMpnY)

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String(base64string.Substring(base64string.IndexOf(',') + 1));` ought to remove the data-url prefix and convert just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `readAsDataURL` method, the `result` contains a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) which is prefixed with the `data:` schema.

From [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL):

> **Note:** The file's result results in a string that cannot be directly decoded as Base64. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, you must remove `data:*/*;base64,` from the string.

So just like Jonathon Chase commented, you would have to remove the schema's prefix either in your Javascript code, before sending it down to your C# web service or in your web service.